# Unable to run docker-machine despite trying to add path

Tags: bash, executable, docker

I downloaded the docker toolkit from [docker](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases). I tried to change the `.basrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment` file by adding `/usr/local/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine` but I am still not able to run docker-machine in the command line. I get a command not found error.

I have docker-machine-Linux-x86_64 file in my `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine` folder. I am only able to run `./docker-machine-Linux-x86_64` when I'm in that folder.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: What does echo $PATH show?   Can you run with the full path : /usr/local/bin/docker-machine/docker-machine-Linux-x86_64 ?

Comment: The full path works too. But trying your solution made docker-machine command work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great -- that's good to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move your existing directory out of the way and re-install per the instructions.    The instructions on the docker page will create the executable in /usr/local/bin/docker-machine, so this conflicts with the structure you have now.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-machine{,.old} # move dir to docker-machine.old
```

change to root, and install via curl (the command here is copied verbatim from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases):

```
sudo -s
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```